# Looking to speed up this max pairwise product

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, max, product

I'm very new to programming, so please go easy on me :)

How can I make the following python code output quicker-

```
n = int(input())
a = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
assert(len(a) == n)

result = 0

for i in range(0, n):
    for j in range(i+1, n):
        if a[i]*a[j] > result:
            result = a[i]*a[j]

print(result)
```

What are some options to maximize its speed?

Answer (score 2):

All you are trying to do is to find two different elements whos product is the biggest. This happens when two numbers are the biggest. So you basically have find two biggest numbers in the array. This can be done in `O(n)`.

One example how this can be done. Find the biggest number and it's position. Save it, remove it and find the max of the result (which will be second biggest). Now multiply both.

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko you are right, In this case first 4 elements can also be found in O(n). And then use your max formula.

Comment: Also consider the product of the two most negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compute the maximal product of distinct integers in a list.
Computing product for every pair has O(N^2) time complexity.

You can reduce this to O(N log(N)) by sorting the list.

```
a = sorted(a)
ans = max(a[0] * a[1], a[-2] * a[-1])
```

You can further improve this to linear time, but I will let you figure it out.

Comment: Finding two biggest numbers can be done in O(n). No need to sort: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37381709/1090562

Comment: As noted in the answer, but yes.

Answer (score 0):

I see, Stepik.org course lesson "Maximum pairwise product":

Try the following, instead of the cascaded for-loop:

```
n1 = max(a)
a.remove(n1)
result = n1*max(a)
```

Which essentially saves the biggest value in a variable, removes it from the sequence, and multiplies it with the now biggest value of the sequence (2nd biggest value in the original sequence).

Comment: So, I see, it's exactly what @Salvador Dali already explained :-)

Comment: This will not work, if the same no are repeated in a sequence

Answer (score 0):

My solution would use sorted and set,as this algorithm work on duplicate items as well.

```
    x, y = sorted(set(nums))[-2:]
    print(x * y)
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this O(n) solution:

```
def maxPairwise(l):
   if len(l) == 2:
       return l[0]*l[1]
   elif len(l) == 1:
       return l[0]
   else:
       max1 = 0
       max2 = 0
       for i in l:
           if i > max1:
               max1 = i
           if i > max2 and i != max1:
               max2 = i
       return max1 * max2
```